# Cannot run pip even when I have the package installed

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, openwrt

I'm new to OpenWrt and I'm trying to use `python3-pip` installed with `opkg`, but even though I have installed it succesfully, I can't run `pip` command (or any other command like `python`, `python3` etc.)

***My goal is to run***

`pip install --upgrade pip`

```
root@OpenWrt:/usr/bin# opkg install python3-pip
Package python3-pip (22.2.2-1) installed in root is up to date.
```

```
root@OpenWrt:/usr/bin# pip
-ash: pip: not found
```

```
root@OpenWrt:/usr/bin# python3
-ash: python3: not found
```

```
root@OpenWrt:/usr/bin# python3-pip
-ash: python3-pip: not found
```

I'm using OpenWrt with
Firmware Version: `OpenWrt SNAPSHOT r20027-586c2426d9 / LuCI Master git-22.167.28356-8effea5`

Kernel Version: `5.10.127`

Arch: `MediaTek MT7688 ver:1 eco:2`

Target Platform: `ramips/mt76x8`

Comment: try 'which pip' to get the install location.

Comment: @CaptainCaveman `/usr/bin/pip`

Comment: What happens when you run /usr/bin/pip?

Comment: @CaptainCaveman `root@OpenWrt:~# /usr/bin/pip
-ash: /usr/bin/pip: not found`

Comment: ok. what is -ash? Also, you may have pip3 installed. 'which pip3'.

Comment: @CaptainCaveman I'm affraid, I don't know, I did't install anything like it. I think its somehow corrupted `bash`. `which pip3` returns `/usr/bin/pip3`

Comment: what does running pip3 result in?

Comment: @CaptainCaveman not found as `pip` does

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250358/discussion-between-captain-caveman-and-krystof18).